# webview_flutter Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread:

Tags: ios, flutter, webview

I am getting the following error with the webview_flutter plugin. It happens only the first time the webview is launched and closed and only happens when you run the app on the physical device.

I am using:
webview_flutter: ^1.0.3

[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.2, ...)

Any clue on how I can go about fixing this? Thank you.

```
=================================================================
Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIView removeFromSuperview]
PID: 14234, TID: 4116224, Thread name: io.flutter.1.raster, Queue name: com.apple.root.default-qos.overcommit, QoS: 0
Backtrace:
4   Flutter                             0x0000000103ffdc70 _ZN7flutter30FlutterPlatformViewsController11SubmitFrameEP15GrDirectContextNSt3__110shared_ptrINS_10IOSContextEEENS3_10unique_ptrINS_12SurfaceFrameENS3_14default_deleteIS8_EEEE + 4932
5   Flutter                             0x0000000104017100 _ZN7flutter10IOSSurface11SubmitFrameEP15GrDirectContextNSt3__110unique_ptrINS_12SurfaceFrameENS3_14default_deleteIS5_EEEE + 160
6   Flutter                             0x00000001042ed764 _ZN7flutter10Rasterizer13DrawToSurfaceERNS_9LayerTreeE + 604
7   Flutter                             0x00000001042ee2a0 _ZNSt3__110__function6__funcIZN7flutter10Rasterizer4DrawEN3fml6RefPtrINS2_8PipelineINS2_9LayerTreeEEEEEE3$_1NS_9allocatorISA_EEFvNS_10unique_ptrIS7_NS_14default_deleteIS7_EEEEEEclEOSG_ + 116
8   Flutter                             0x00000001042eda64 _ZN7flutter10Rasterizer4DrawEN3fml6RefPtrINS_8PipelineINS_9LayerTreeEEEEE + 408
9   Flutter                             0x00000001042f42b0 _ZNSt3__110__function6__funcIZN7flutter5Shell14OnAnimatorDrawEN3fml6RefPtrINS2_8PipelineINS2_9LayerTreeEEEEENS4_9TimePointEE4$_30NS_9allocatorISB_EEFvvEEclEv + 100
10  Flutter                             0x0000000104021fe8 _ZN3fml15MessageLoopImpl10FlushTasksENS_9FlushTypeE + 1472
11  Flutter                             0x0000000104024714 _ZN3fml17MessageLoopDarwin11OnTimerFireEP16__CFRunLoopTimerPS0_ + 32
12  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000191ac4274 50CF3336-313F-3A7D-9048-CB1ED8EC3368 + 692852
13  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000191ac3f90 50CF3336-313F-3A7D-9048-CB1ED8EC3368 + 692112
14  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000191ac366c 50CF3336-313F-3A7D-9048-CB1ED8EC3368 + 689772
15  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000191abe67c 50CF3336-313F-3A7D-9048-CB1ED8EC3368 + 669308
16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000191abdce8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
17  Flutter                             0x00000001040245f0 _ZN3fml17MessageLoopDarwin3RunEv + 88
18  Flutter                             0x00000001040237cc _ZNSt3__114__thread_proxyINS_5tupleIJNS_10unique_ptrINS_15__thread_structENS_14default_deleteIS3_EEEEZN3fml6ThreadC1ERKNS_12basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEEE3$_0EEEEEPvSJ_ + 196
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000019185bd98 _pthread_start + 156
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000019185f74c thread_start + 8
2020-10-18 16:25:04.959679-0400 Runner[14234:4116224] [reports] Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIView removeFromSuperview]
PID: 14234, TID: 4116224, Thread name: io.flutter.1.raster, Queue name: com.apple.root.default-qos.overcommit, QoS: 0
Backtrace:
4   Flutter                             0x0000000103ffdc70 _ZN7flutter30FlutterPlatformViewsController11SubmitFrameEP15GrDirectContextNSt3__110shared_ptrINS_10IOSContextEEENS3_10unique_ptrINS_12SurfaceFrameENS3_14default_deleteIS8_EEEE + 4932
5   Flutter                             0x0000000104017100 _ZN7flutter10IOSSurface11SubmitFrameEP15GrDirectContextNSt3__110unique_ptrINS_12SurfaceFrameENS3_14default_deleteIS5_EEEE + 160
6   Flutter                             0x00000001042ed764 _ZN7flutter10Rasterizer13DrawToSurfaceERNS_9LayerTreeE + 604
7   Flutter                             0x00000001042ee2a0 _ZNSt3__110__function6__funcIZN7flutter10Rasterizer4DrawEN3fml6RefPtrINS2_8PipelineINS2_9LayerTreeEEEEEE3$_1NS_9allocatorISA_EEFvNS_10unique_ptrIS7_NS_14default_deleteIS7_EEEEEEclEOSG_ + 116
8   Flutter                             0x00000001042eda64 _ZN7flutter10Rasterizer4DrawEN3fml6RefPtrINS_8PipelineINS_9LayerTreeEEEEE + 408
9   Flutter                             0x00000001042f42b0 _ZNSt3__110__function6__funcIZN7flutter5Shell14OnAnimatorDrawEN3fml6RefPtrINS2_8PipelineINS2_9LayerTreeEEEEENS4_9TimePointEE4$_30NS_9allocatorISB_EEFvvEEclEv + 100
10  Flutter                             0x0000000104021fe8 _ZN3fml15MessageLoopImpl10FlushTasksENS_9FlushTypeE + 1472
11  Flutter                             0x0000000104024714 _ZN3fml17MessageLoopDarwin11OnTimerFireEP16__CFRunLoopTimerPS0_ + 32
12  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000191ac4274 50CF3336-313F-3A7D-9048-CB1ED8EC3368 + 692852
13  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000191ac3f90 50CF3336-313F-3A7D-9048-CB1ED8EC3368 + 692112
14  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000191ac366c 50CF3336-313F-3A7D-9048-CB1ED8EC3368 + 689772
15  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000191abe67c 50CF3336-313F-3A7D-9048-CB1ED8EC3368 + 669308
16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000191abdce8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
17  Flutter                             0x00000001040245f0 _ZN3fml17MessageLoopDarwin3RunEv + 88
18  Flutter                             0x00000001040237cc _ZNSt3__114__thread_proxyINS_5tupleIJNS_10unique_ptrINS_15__thread_structENS_14default_deleteIS3_EEEEZN3fml6ThreadC1ERKNS_12basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEEE3$_0EEEEEPvSJ_ + 196
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000019185bd98 _pthread_start + 156
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000019185f74c thread_start + 8
2020-10-18 16:25:13.101480-0400 Runner[14234:4116085] [ProcessSuspension] 0x12bbe1ec0 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
```

Comment: We're seeing this issue too...

Comment: Any solution / walkaround?